# Where can I obtain my Azure AD B2C Issuer URL in the Portal

Tags: oauth-2.0, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

Currently trying to configure "Advanced" authorization/authentication for my Azure Functions using an Azure AD B2C directory. In order to do so it is stating that I need an issuer URL:

[image]

When I navigate to the app that I've set up in Azure AD B2C and select endpoints, I am presented with several urls, however it is unclear to me which one represents the "Issuer URL". Also what should be put in place for "policy-name". I've set up a user flow for login, but would this also support client credentials flow?:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this format:

`https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy name}`

Select any of your user flows or custom policies and you will see this URL at the top of the blade.

[image]

Comment: No - B2C doesn't currently support client credentials.

Comment: You can "fudge" it using Azure AD - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#daemonsserver-side-applications

Comment: Yea I came across that document shortly after posting this confirming that client credentials flow is not "directly" supported at this time

Comment: @rbrayb Thanks I forgot to answer this question. Yes B2C doesn't currently support client credentials.