# Azure B2C: Unable to retrieve document from v2.0 .well-known openid-configuration

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, openid

I am trying to use Azure B2C in my dotnet core web app in order to use a sign-in flow I created.

These are my appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://XXXX.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "Domain": "XXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "<CLIENT_ID>",
    "TenantId": "<TENANT_ID>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignFlow"
 }
```

This is my Startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(
        IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        services.AddRepositories(this.Configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddServices();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
            options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
        });

        // Configuration to sign-in users with Azure AD B2C
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(this.Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C);

        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions> (this.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IWebHostEnvironment env,
        ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Starting Migration");
            using var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
            logger.LogInformation("Finished Migration");
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                "default",
                "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        }

        );
    }
```

The issue: Everytime I start my application, I get the following error:

```
System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://XXXX.b2clogin.com/<TENANT_ID>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  ...
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 103
 }', HttpResponseMessage.Content: 'The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.'.
```

If I simply want to use Microsoft authentication, and set my instance name to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/`, everything works as expected. This only happens when I attempt to use user flows.

If I try to remove the `TenantId` from the appsettings.json, I get a message saying it is required : `The 'TenantId' option must be provided`.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add "Authority" in the appsettings.json. which is the meta data url

(authority format: "https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" )

```
"AzureAdB2C": { 

    "Authority":"https://<tenantname>.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_{signup_policy}/v2.0/ ", 

   
 "Instance": "https://XXXX.b2clogin.com/tfp/", 

    "Domain": "XXXX.onmicrosoft.com", 

    "ClientId": "<CLIENT_ID>", 

    "TenantId": "<TENANT_ID>", 

    "CallbackPath": "/b2csignin", 

    "SignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignFlow" 

 },
```

And provide the generic issuer url in portal/codesomething like below

```
https:// <domain>/tfp/<tenantId>/v2/
```

(or)
policy specific issuer

```
https:// <domain>/tfp/<tenantId>/b2c_1_ policy/v2/
```

**References**

1. [getting-error-when-trying-to-secure-aspnet-core-web-api-](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/332f1b1d-e4e5-4fa9-aa68-e4428109024c/getting-error-when-trying-to-secure-aspnet-core-web-api-with-b2c-bearer-authentication-unable-to)
2. [azure-ad-b2c-issuer-url-in-the-portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201234/where-can-i-obtain-my-azure-ad-b2c-issuer-url-in-the-portal)