# Azure AD B2C fails to get config after upgrading kubernetes

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory

We have upgraded our local instance of Kubernetes to 1.28.2 but after the upgrade we get the exception below in multiple dev environments. The same code works correctly on the prior version (1.25.2).

```
Exception caught in global error handler, exception message: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://mydirectory.b2clogin.com/mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_MYPOLICY/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'., exception stack:    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
```

```
....
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://mydirectory.b2clogin.com/mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_MYPOLICY/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://mydirectory.b2clogin.com/mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_MYPOLICY/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

If I paste the URL into a browser it works correctly and shows the openid configuration.

The config for AD is unchanged with the upgraded k8s but this is what we have in the service. This worked prior to the upgrade.

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://mydirectory.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXX"
  },
```

I can see in the network traffic that the auth is successful and a token is returned and provided on the request.

I've added this to the `Startup.cs` in the service:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

To no effect. What could be causing the communication to that service to fail?

Edit: Confirmed that downgrading to an earlier version of Kubernetes resolves the issue. Not clear what would be different in the upgraded version of Docker or k8s.

Comment: Maybe the network policies have changed recently? See [`docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies.md`](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/commits/main/content/en/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies.md)

Comment: try using `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` or `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault`

Comment: Probably this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314606/azure-b2c-unable-to-retrieve-document-from-v2-0-well-known-openid-configuratio

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu I've looked at that one with no resolution. This is something specific to the k8s upgrade since everything works on 1.27 but fails on 1.28