# Is it possible to use a token acquired by Azure SWA to authenticate against a separate Azure Function (not the linked API)

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure static web app where I "bring my own function" as the API and authenticate using Azure AD B2C.

Now I'm facing the problem that the maximum request size on SWA is 30 MB, so I was wondering if I can authenticate against a separate Azure Function with the token issued by Azure AD B2C to the SWA web application?

I have [tried to setup authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad?tabs=workforce-tenant#-step-2-enable-microsoft-entra-id-in-your-app-service-app) on the new Azure Function:

- using the same app registration as the SWA
- added the new Azure Function url as Web Redirect URI in the app registration
- used the sign in user flow as issuer URL ([following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66202534/2050637))

but I can not get it working.

It could be a configuration issue or maybe it is not possible.

If it is possible I will add further info to this question if needed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to use a token acquired by Azure SWA to authenticate against a separate Azure Function (not the linked API)

Comment: @Rukmini If you are confident on this, create an answer and I will mark it as solution ;)